# Matlab: obtaining the normals of binary image contour points

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

**Context**

I have a binary image of a silhouette that I wish to add noise to. The noise should be added only to the contour of the silhouette. I would like the noise to be a vector that is added to each contour point, with the length of the vector being sampled from a Gaussian distribution with zero-mean and a variance of x% of the silhouette height. The direction of the vector should be the normal of the given contour point.

**Question**

In Matlab, given a binary image, how do I obtain the normals of the contour points?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`bwboundaries`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) to obtain the contour (i.e. the sequence of points which make the contour). Since you have the sequence of points thanks to `bwboundaries`, we can now define 3 points *A,B,C* where *B* is between *A* and *C* and we want to find the normal at *B* which is given by:

```
N = [Ay - Cy;Cx - Ax]';
```